# Writing nested JSON in spark scala

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

My Spark-SQL is generating an output for a query by joining two tables which has one to many cardinality. I have to convert the data into JSON.
This is how the output of the query will look like.

```
Address_id_parent | Address_id_child | Country_child | city_child
1                 |      1           |     India     |    Delhi
1                 |      1           |     US        |    NewYork
1                 |      1           |     US        |    NewJersey
```

The above data has to be converted to JSON in this way.

```
{
    "Address": {
        "Address_id_parent": "1"
    },
    "Address-details": [{
        "Address_id_child": "1",
        "location": [{
                 "country":"India",
                 "city":"Delhi",
                },
                {
                 "country":"US",
                 "city":"NewYork",
                },
                {
                 "country":"US",
                 "city":"NewJersey",
                }
                ]
    }]
}
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: did achieved this in spark scala?

Answer (score 0):

Check Dataframe write interface with json:

```
df.write.format("json").save(path)
```

Comment: how can do the reverse? and put it in a table in a denormalized form?