# how do i convert a flat dataframe into a nested json in spark (scala or java)

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, dataframe, nested

I have sql query which returns the data set like this available in dataframe

```
id,type,name,ppu,batter.id,batter.type,topping.id,topping.type
101,donut,cake,0_55,1001,Regular,5001,None
101,donut,cake,0_55,1002,Chocolate,5001,None
101,donut,cake,0_55,1003,Blueberry,5001,None
101,donut,cake,0_55,1004,Devil's Food,5001,None
101,donut,cake,0_55,1001,Regular,5002,Glazed
101,donut,cake,0_55,1002,Chocolate,5002,Glazed
101,donut,cake,0_55,1003,Blueberry,5002,Glazed
101,donut,cake,0_55,1004,Devil's Food,5002,Glazed
101,donut,cake,0_55,1001,Regular,5003,Chocolate
101,donut,cake,0_55,1002,Chocolate,5003,Chocolate
101,donut,cake,0_55,1003,Blueberry,5003,Chocolate
101,donut,cake,0_55,1004,Devil's Food,5003,Chocolate
```

I need to cover this into a nested json structure like this.

```
{
    "id": "101",
    "type": "donut",
    "name": "Cake",
    "ppu": 0.55,
    "batter":
        [
            { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
            { "id": "1002", "type": "Chocolate" },
            { "id": "1003", "type": "Blueberry" },
            { "id": "1004", "type": "Devil's Food" }
        ],
    "topping":
        [
            { "id": "5001", "type": "None" },
            { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" },
            { "id": "5003", "type": "Chocolate" }
        ]
}
```

do we have possibility to perform this in Dataframe aggregation or custom transformation i have to write.

Found similar question here 
[Writing nested JSON in spark scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325742/writing-nested-json-in-spark-scala)
but doesnt have quite right answer.

Answer (score 0):

So, apparently there is no straight way to do this task via the dataframe API. You could use the

```
df.toJson.{..}
```

but it wont give you the output you want.

You'll have to write a messy transform, I'd love to hear any other possible solutions. I'm assuming that your result fits in memory as it must be brought back to the driver. Also, I'm using Gson API to create the json here.

```
def arrToJson(arr: Array[Row]): JsonObject = {
    val jo = new JsonObject
    arr.map(row => ((row(0) + "," + row(1) + "," + row(2) + "," + row(3)),
      (row(4) + "," + row(5) + "," + row(6) + "," + row(7))))
      .groupBy(_._1).map(f => (f._1.split(","), f._2.map(_._2.split(","))))
      .foreach { x =>
        {

          jo.addProperty("id", x._1(0))
          jo.addProperty("type", x._1(1))
          jo.addProperty("name", x._1(2))
          jo.addProperty("ppu", x._1(3))

          val bja = new JsonArray
          val tja = new JsonArray
          x._2.foreach(f => {
            val bjo = new JsonObject
            val tjo = new JsonObject

            bjo.addProperty("id", f(0))
            bjo.addProperty("type", f(1))

            tjo.addProperty("id", f(2))
            tjo.addProperty("type", f(3))

            bja.add(bjo)
            tja.add(tjo)
          })
          jo.add("batter", bja)
          jo.add("topping", tja)

        }
      }

    jo
  }
```

Comment: Thank you Chitral, but unfortunately this can become complex in my case with 100+ columns and atleast 2 level of nesting. Also in my case the data may not fit into driver so i look to transform in distributed nodes. I was able to do to some extent using UDAF, but can work only for simple objects with only one nested object. I heard Spark 2.0 has better support for that. but not sure. Thanks again for trying :)